# Xml-conduit parsing for text inside links

Tags: haskell

I would like to extract the text contents from the below Html page. All the paragraphs from the `<div>`.
I use the [xml-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.2.0.1) package for html parsing and came up with the following code:

```
getWebPageContents :: Url -> IO [T.Text]
getWebPageContents u = do
    cursor <- cursorFor u
    return $ cursor $// filter &/ content


filter = element "div" >=> attributeIs "id" "article-body-blocks" &// element "p"
```

This will return most of the text but not the ones from the links(*"front page of today's Daily Mirror"*)

Could anyone help?
[image: example html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter to all the *descendants* of the `p` tags, not just the children. You probably just need to replace `&/ content` with `&// content`.